# Is there a way to feed downloaded xml continuously into XMLPullParser?

Tags: python, elementtree

In my python script, I'm downloading some XML from a url. It contains the a list of elements within the root element. It really takes quite some time to do so and since the documentation of etree suggested to use the XMLPullParser for things like that, I wanted to try it, but didn't find any way of continuously reading the url into the XMLPullParser. I had hoped to already be able to process the list entries one by one that way, while still downloading. Anyone any idea?

Comment: What are you using for downloading?

Comment: Depends on what is capable of doing what i want. At the moment, I'm using requests library to download and process data afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `urllib.request.urlopen` from the standard library. Like `open`, you can use this as a context manager;

```
with urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.python.org/") as uf:
    while True:
        data = uf.read(1024)  # read returns empty string when finished.
        if data:
            # feed to pullparser here...
            print(data)
        else:
            break;
```